# Clone failed from Azure hosted source code with certificate error

Tags: git, azure, git-clone

When we are getting clone of the source code which is hosted in Windows Azure getting the below error fatal: Authentication failed for 'source code url'

while trying with the below command  git -c http.sslVerify=false clone 'source code URL' getting the below error

warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------

warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |

warning: ---------------------------------------------------

warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.

error fatal: Authentication failed for 'source code url'

Can any one help me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: The *warning* is because you added `-c http.sslVerify=false`. If you don't want the warning, don't add the `-c` option. The "authentication failed" is because your credential helper supplied the wrong user and/or password as credentials.

Comment: @torek how we can see or change the username and password in credential helper

Comment: That depends on which credential helper you're using. Which one did you choose, or if you did not choose one, which OS and Git installation are you using since some Git installers set an OS-specific one? Alternatively, you can pick a specific credential helper. The one you'll want is OS-dependent. Do a search for "git credential helper".